# Recovering an image using IDCT through DCT coefficients

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transform, dct

I have computed the discrete cosine transform (DCT) of an image in MATLAB. I got a matrix of discrete cosine transform coefficients in the workspace. How can I recover the original image from its discrete cosine transform coefficients in MATLAB?

Comment: Apparently you already have the knowledge of the DCT/IDCT function. Do you have a specific issue? Color image, integer calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `dct2`  on an image, or on each image channel separately for color images,  with the appropriate input format, then `idct2` recover the original image (the transformation is invertible and orthogonal), up to rounding errors (similar discussion in [Why is $\exp(\ln(x))−x\neq 0$ in floating point arithmetic?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23782/why-is-exp-lnx-x-neq0-in-floating-point-arithmetic)).

You can find for instance a demo below:

```
dataRGB = double(imread('autumn.tif'));
data = rgb2gray(dataRGB/255);
dataDct=  dct2(data);
dataDctIdct = idct2(dataDct);

subplot(2,2,1)
imagesc(data); 
xlabel('Original (grayscale)');
subplot(2,2,2)
imagesc(log(abs(dataDct))); 
xlabel('Original DCT');
subplot(2,2,3)
imagesc(dataDctIdct); 
xlabel('Original recovered');
subplot(2,2,4)
imagesc(data-dataDctIdct); 
xlabel('Difference'); 
colorbar
colormap gray
```